# Can ios apps be written with Xcode 2.4?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

With a PowerBook G4 running Mac OSX 10.4, the most up-to-date XCode I can possibly run is 2.4. While it doesn't have storyboards or the handy templates (Single view application, tabbed, etc), it does at least allow you to create a Cocoa Application or empty project. Is there anything that would prevent me from creating a single ios app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Now apple not allow you to upload if Xcode version is not latest.

Comment: Interesting. So, Apple expects developers to be using a computer that at the very least can run xcode 5.0? (what about 6?)

Comment: You can upload apps using Xcode 5. Xcode 6 is not allowed yet because it is still in beta.